# Check the column is null or not in concating column?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, concatenation

I am using sequelize and node.js. I want to concat the value of columns of info models. when one of the column's value is null in response returns ', ' . I want check if the value of columns is null it just return empty. How can I solve this?

```
{
            model: info,
            as: "info",
            attributes: [
              [
                Sequelize.fn('CONCAT',
                  Sequelize.col('country'), ', ',
                  Sequelize.col('city'), ', ',
                  Sequelize.col('street'), ', ',
                  Sequelize.col('phone'), ', ',
                ),
                'address'
              ],
            ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why no one answered it but you can try this

```
{
  model: info,
  as: "info",
  attributes: [
    [
      Sequelize.fn('CONCAT',
        Sequelize.literal(`CASE WHEN country is NULL THEN '' ELSE country END`), 
        Sequelize.literal(`CASE WHEN country is NULL THEN '' ELSE ',' END`),
        Sequelize.literal(`CASE WHEN city is NULL THEN '' ELSE city END`), 
        Sequelize.literal(`CASE WHEN city is NULL THEN '' ELSE ',' END`),
        Sequelize.literal(`CASE WHEN street is NULL THEN '' ELSE street END`), 
        Sequelize.literal(`CASE WHEN street is NULL THEN '' ELSE ',' END`),
        Sequelize.literal(`CASE WHEN phone is NULL THEN '' ELSE phone END`), 
        Sequelize.literal(`CASE WHEN phone is NULL THEN '' ELSE ',' END`),
      ),
      'address'
    ],
  ],
}
```

There can be more ways but this what I think can be one way to resolve the problem.